# Get data from Oracle into Infopath

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, infopath, infopath-data-connections, oracle

I'm trying to get data from Oracle into InfoPath. I have created a linked server.

I am getting data connection base `OPENQUERY`:

```
  select * from OPENQUERY (ORADB, 'select * from DBCUSTOMER where ....')
```

Is it advisable to dynamically input WHERE in SQL data connection from InfoPath variables?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Unfortunately,** you can't add dynamic values from Infopath variables to the `Where clause` when you configure the data connection for database source.

**In general**, when you configure a data connection form database (SQL / OLE DB provider for Oracle), there is no option to add where clause.

[image]

In this case, you should `Edit SQL Statment` to provide where clause manually with static data!!

[image]

**The available workaround** is to use `Filter Data` and specify your conditions that depend on InfoPath fields based on your requirements.

[image]